# Getting java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to complete the HTTP request while uploading document

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gdata-api

I am getting timeout error while I am trying to upload document using com.google.gdata.client.docs.DocsService

here is the code I am using:

```
DocumentListEntry documentEntry = new DocumentEntry();

documentEntry.setTitle(new PlainTextConstruct("new document"));

documentEntry.setMediaSource(new MediaByteArraySource(out.toByteArray(), mimeType));

DocumentListEntry uploadedEntry = service.insert(new URL("https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full/"), documentEntry);   <-- timeout at this point.
```

Timeout while fetching: https://docs.google.com/feeds/default/private/full/

I am running application in debug mode using app engine sdk in eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a very old thread, but just saw it while replying another question. I hope you have resolved it by now.

If not, then is your service authenticated and are you able to create a simple document e.g.

```
             String title = "Doc Create Test";
             DocumentListEntry newEntry = new DocumentEntry();
             newEntry.setTitle(new PlainTextConstruct(title));
             newEntry = service.insert(feedUrl, newEntry);
```